# Can't commit to SVN [500 internal server error]

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg-2.0

Recently svn is returning error 500 to tortoise when we trying commit  some files .pdf and .js ([printscreen](http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ql8sue&s=8#.VNYD7S4plpk))

I am using windows 7, tortoise last version, and i turned off my antivirus

I emailed  to server team, but they have not found the solution

Comment: How does Mercurial fit into this?

Answer (score 1):

an internal server error is always an error on the server side. The only way to get more information on this is to check the Apache error log file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Password is expired or not by Deleting the SVN credentials and try committing again. It worked for me follow the below steps.

Type %APPDATA% in windows start and open the folder location. Navigate to svn.simple folder (Roaming -> Subversion -> auth -> svn.simple). Delete the file present in this folder. Move to eclipse, Right click on the Project, Team -> Cleanup. Now try committing.